# Get longitude and latitude using android Geofire

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to get users location using Geo fire for android. I was trying to get the users longitude and latitude and save it in the firebase database, but I had no luck.

Below is my code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_registration);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    savebutton=findViewById(R.id.save);

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference update = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);

    GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(rootRef);

    geoFire.getLocation("location", new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if(location!=null){

                Double longi = location.longitude;
                Double lat = location.latitude;

                update.child("longitude").setValue(longi);
                update.child("latitude").setValue(lat);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: @PeterHaddad I don't get any error its just that the longitude and latitude is not  showing on the database

Comment: @GCode22 likely the structure of nodes does not look as it is being expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GeoFire you can set and query locations by string keys. To set a location for a key simply call the setLocation method:

```
geoFire.setLocation("location", new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String key, FirebaseError error) {
        if (error != null) {
            System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Location saved on server successfully!");
        }
    }
});
```

After setting the location, you can then retrieve it and save the values to the database:

```
geoFire.getLocation("location", new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The location for key %s is [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude))
// save longitude and latitude to db
            Double longi = location.longitude;
            Double lat = location.latitude
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("There is no location for key %s in GeoFire", key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.err.println("There was an error getting the GeoFire location: " + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Add a log and check the value of longitude

Comment: I don't see it @Peter

Comment: Then it's not entering the callback `LocationCallback()`

Comment: How do I fix this. I'm kind of new to using geofire. Can you help me out here please

Comment: Did you use `setLocation` first to set the location?

Comment: No i did not I just used getLocation

Comment: That is the mistake

Comment: ok after I set the location whats next? can you write down everything that I need to please